# Group product import csv issue in magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I am using magento 2.2.6

I am importing group product with associate product via csv (added all product in db)

but issue is simple product string sku not assigning in to group product
(simple product with numeric sku is working but not working string sku)

can you please guide me what i do for that

Comment: Check below link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12793

Comment: does your sku has Capital letters??

Comment: yes SKU has capital letters

Comment: okk. that may be the issue as i have read one comment in github issue thread,check last comment in given thread link